# Can I remove the internal cells of my removable battery of my laptop and connect the wires to my AC adapter pin?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

Can I do that?
My situation is very desperate and I cannot get help nearby for nearly 15 days.

The problem is that my laptop stops charging after a certain stress level(running more softwares /playing heavy games) and each time it stops charging, well the stress level on which it stops charging drops even more.
but my laptop seems to work fine with only battery.
I had the same problem few weeks ago and it was fixed by replacing an IC and a MOSFET in the power distribution section of my motherboard, the engineer said that these two worn out over time and have been replaced, But the problem seems to be coming back again.

So I was wondering if I remove all the cells in my battery and manually connect the +ve and -ve wires to the charging pin of my adapter.

And another point, my laptop shuts down immediately at the stress level like a power cut-out when it runs on without battery(obviously with adapter connected).

Comment: some laptops use the battery itself also (and the AC) when there is a very high load, like some HP laptops. it is very unlikely that your plan would function as desired, unless you had a AC adapter that is of the correct replacement battery voltage, of sufficient amps to cover these high loads.  it is more likely that the battery is in need of replacement, and that a bad battery could have caused some issues with the power IC and mosfet which should not age to failure as claimed.  Much like having a really bad battery in your car, can cause your car regulator and alternator to fail prematurely

Comment: The power ratings don't match...